# WCF hosted in Windows Service with wsHttpBindngs points to wrong location

Tags: c#, wcf, service, windows-services

In short, when I use the same config in IIS I can see this:

[image]

and when I go to my `Service1` I can see the 'wsdl' info.

Now, when I stop IIS and start my Windows Service with the same config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="https://localhost:443/WcfService1"/>
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
            <endpoint address=""
                                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                                contract="WcfService1.IService1"
                                bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBindingConfiguration"/>

            <endpoint address="ws"
                                binding="wsHttpBinding"
                                contract="WcfService1.IService1"
                                bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBindingConfiguration"
                behaviorConfiguration="wsBehaviorConfig"/>

            <endpoint address="mex"
                                binding="mexHttpsBinding"
                                contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="basicHttpBindingConfiguration">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="wsHttpBindingConfiguration">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <client />
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="wsBehaviorConfig">
                <!-- <wsdlExtensions location="https://localhost:443/WcfService1/Service1.svc" singleFile="true" /> -->
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

When I refresh the web page at `https://localhost/WcfService1` I see the WSDL info: [image]

In result, I can't talk to the service. I don't get what I might be doing wrong. Any suggenstions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first case you are experiencing default behavior of started project based on 'WCF Service Application' template. You are presented with project folder content at given address.

In second case you are presented with description 'how to consume your service page' because you have GET page enabled

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
```

If you want to consume your service then you need to 'add service reference' from your client-app or to create proxy manually.

Comment: And this needs to done in application that is calling my service? If so, I can't really do this as I don't have access to the code.

Comment: @Jakubee, once you create your service(s) you should test it with WcfTestClient or(and) with another application by adding service reference. With this you can test and gain confidence that your service is working as expected.

Comment: @Jakubee, there is detailed explanation on **MSDN** for [WCF Test Client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364(v=vs.110).aspx)

Shortest possible way to use would be, find **Developer Command Prompt for VS2015** and run it, then add service reference (File/Add Service ...), enter address to yours service and if all is correct, you will be presented to callable interface to methods of yours service

Comment: I've spend a lot of time on this but manage to get this working. Thanks!